# Does the postgres COPY function support utf 16 encoded files?

Tags: postgresql, encoding, character-encoding, utf-16

I am trying to use the postgreSQL `COPY` function to insert a UTF 16 encoded csv into a table. However, when running the below query:

```
COPY temp 
FROM 'C:\folder\some_file.csv' 
WITH (
    DELIMITER E'\t', 
    FORMAT csv, 
    HEADER);
```

I get the error below:

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff
CONTEXT:  COPY temp, line 1
SQL state: 22021
```

and when I run the same query, but adding the encoding settings `Encoding 'UTF-16'` or `Encoding 'UTF 16'` to the with block, I get the error below:

```
ERROR:  argument to option "encoding" must be a valid encoding name
LINE 13:  ENCODING 'UTF 16' );
          ^
SQL state: 22023
Character: 377
```

I've looked through the postgres documentation to try to find the correct encoding, but haven't managed to find anything. Is this because the copy function does support UTF 16 encoded files? I would have thought that this would almost certainly have been possible!

I'm running postgres 12, on windows 10 pro

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do that.

UTF-16 is not in the [list of supported encodings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html#MULTIBYTE-CHARSET-SUPPORTED).
PostgreSQL will never support an encoding that is not an extension of ASCII.
You will have to convert the file to UTF-8.